# Kotlin runBlocking on background thread

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm in the process of converting an existing app from Java to Kotlin. 
The app creates an **IntentService** which runs in a background thread and is tasked to perform some operations which block the thread (e.g. network calls, database interactions) with `suspend` functions repeatedly and indefinitely. 
Since the "current thread" is in fact a background thread I'm not blocking the UI.

Is it a good practice to make use of `runBlocking` on the current thread to run all the suspending functions? Or there is a better approach?

Comment: The background thread of your service is used to deliver notifications from the system. So if you use it for potentially long operations - you will not be able to receive new events from the system. And for that case, you do not need any `suspend` functions to play with. 
The alternative is to offload the execution to a dedicated thread pool, not free the background thread for the text notifications. Here you may prefer `launch` or `async` functions instead

Comment: I use the background thread to send data to a webservice and update the app database every x seconds, and the thread needs to run in background for potentially hours (I used IntentService for that purpose). I will edit my question in order to be clearer

Comment: What's the point of using coroutines if you plan to block the thread?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik because I need to use some already-defined Kotlin functions that are suspend functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is exactly the usage of `runBlocking`. `runBlocking` was added to coroutines to create a bridge between the users of `coroutines` and other places that are executing the code blockingly. If you want a thread to be blocked and wait for the execution of a a coroutine, you should always use `runBlocking`.